# How to deal with popups in Playwright?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, popup, playwright

I want to delete an article, on the normal site I usually click on the Delete button and then I see the popup in which I have to confirm my choice.

So, here is my code

```js
const {test, expect} = require('@playwright/test');
const { createNewArticle, generateRandomUser, generateRandomArticle } = require('../../helpers');

test.only('should delete an article after clicking on [Delete Article]', async ({page}) => {
  const user = generateRandomUser();
  const article = generateRandomArticle();

  const r = await createNewArticle(user, article);

  const slug = r.data.article.slug;

  const {email, password} = user;

  await page.goto('https://conduit.mate.academy/user/login');

  // await page.pause();

  await page.getByPlaceholder('Email').fill(email);
  await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill(password);
  await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();

  await page.waitForURL('https://conduit.mate.academy/')

  await page.goto(`https://conduit.mate.academy/article/${slug}`);

  await page.locator('.btn.btn-outline-danger.btn-sm').first().click();

  await page.goto(`https://conduit.mate.academy/profile/${user.username}`);

  await expect(page.locator('.article-preview')).toHaveCount(1);
  await expect(page.locator('.article-preview')).toHaveText('No articles are here... yet.');
})
```

Here is the reason it fails [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdzWE.png)
So, on this site if there is no articles then this caption is shown No articles are here... yet." But for some reason it found the article that should have been deleted.

When I look into trace, then I see this [trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSA49.png)
So, it finds elements it clicks on it, but it just wasn't deleted.

I assume that this can be because of the popup, when I'm on the site I should confirm with popup that I want to delete the article, but when I'm in Playwright I didn't see it, I read that Playwright didn't handle them by default, so I tried to start with basic of working with popups and added this line of code

```js
const popup = await page.waitForEvent('popup');
```

After that I got this error [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg7jV.png)
So, can someone please point out what can be the reason?

I thought only about popups, so I went to the documentation, chatGPT, youtube videos and tried to use some codes like this one

```js
const popup = await page.waitForEvent('popup');

await popup.waitForFunction(() => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  for (const button of buttons) {
    if (button.innerText === 'OK') {
      button.click();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
```

But anyway it just timed out because it was waiting for this popup and it didn't appear.

Comment: There is lot of unrelated code to the problem. See this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don´t await waitForEvent before you click delete, that way your code wont continue executing before the delete button is pressed. I modified your code with one way to solve it with [page.on('dialog')](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-event-dialog), not popup:

```js
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test');
const { createNewArticle, generateRandomUser, generateRandomArticle } = require('../../helpers');

test.only('should delete an article after clicking on [Delete Article]', async ({ page }) => {
    const user = generateRandomUser();
    const article = generateRandomArticle();

    const r = await createNewArticle(user, article);

    const slug = r.data.article.slug;

    const { email, password } = user;

    await page.goto('https://conduit.mate.academy/user/login');

    await page.getByPlaceholder('Email').fill(email);
    await page.getByPlaceholder('Password').fill(password);
    await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Sign in' }).click();

    await page.waitForURL('https://conduit.mate.academy/')
    
    await page.goto(`https://conduit.mate.academy/article/${slug}`);
    
    // 1. Initiate event listener
    page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
        // 3. Do stuff with the dialog here (reject/accept etc.)
        console.log(dialog.message());
        await dialog.accept()
    });
    // 2. Press the delete button
    await page.locator('.btn.btn-outline-danger.btn-sm').first().click();

    // 4. Execution continues:
    await page.goto(`https://conduit.mate.academy/profile/${user.username}`);

    await expect(page.locator('.article-preview')).toHaveCount(1);
    await expect(page.locator('.article-preview')).toHaveText('No articles are here... yet.');
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for me, I read some documentation about the page.on and now it's clear to me and I got that it was my mistake that I waited for the popup before clicking on the button. Thanks for pointing this out.